# My CodeNameOne-App stopped to work in HTTPS

Tags: codenameone

My App until last week was making all requests using http. 
All was working fine.
Today, back-end server  changed its protocol to HTTPS.
I did some corrections in my code, changing http to https.
After that, my app stoped to work.

Additional informations:

I observed through CodeNameOne-Network-Monitor that all HTTPS-REQUESTS don't have its body-content. Only  header is going out when the protocol is https.
All back to work when protocol returns to http and the Body-Content appears normally in Network-Monitor.

I overrode  the buildRequestBody method of ConnectionRequest Class to generate some Json parameters (project requirements). but I suppose  this fact doesn't  interfere (or shouldn't interfere) on how "ConectionRequest object" executes its http/https requests. My code of buildRequestBody is very similar to parent code.
It only changes the format of content to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP/S transition is normally seamless and the network monitor should show the information since it intercepts it before the data is encrypted. If the information isn't there it means that the body wasn't sent/reached and something failed sooner. I'm guessing there is an exception in the console possibly related to certificate issues that you are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is occurring exactly what you said.
A silent exception occurs caused by invalid server certificate.
I was executing my tests making https-requests to a server with certificate that isn't validated from a legal Authority. Then,  I changed to other server that has a valid certificate installed. After that, my https requests started to work too. The simulator started to show all informations about https requests as it do for http.